# There is issue between tableview and scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

When I Scroll the table View.The screens get jumped. I have TableView within View ,View within the Scroll View.

I have refer the following link.
[conflict scrolling scrollview and tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188992/conflict-scrolling-scrollview-and-tableview)

I couldn't get the clear solution.

Please provide me input on this.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer to your linked question suggests, you should **not** put a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` as their scrolling will just conflict.  Get rid of the `UIScrollView` and use a header or footer if you need some more static view at the top or bottom of your `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid bounce of ScrollView when we scroll the tableview. I have added the below line of code.It worked for me.

```
  self.scrollView.delegate = self
     scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500)
     scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
     scrollView.tag = 1

   func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.tag != 1 {
            self.scrollView.bounces = false
        }
    }
```

Thanks